# How do you make a 2 column body layout with a fixed "nav"

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm a beginner so I'm sure this an easy one. I am trying to replicate the image below, in which the left list/links is fixed so it stays in position as you scroll down the images (I might add a 3rd column too for a fixed description). I tried using `float: left;` for both the links and images (I also tried `float: right;` for the images too), but once I put `position: fixed;` for the links, it automatically moves the images to the far left or right.

The container is 960px (220 for the links, 420 for the images, and 320 for the description).

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="about">
        <ul id="print_list">
            <li><a href="eff.html"><span style="color: #b13c19">Earth Friendly
                      Foods </span> </a></li>
            <li> <a href="tmad.html"> Trivedi Museum of Art and Design </a></li>
            <li> <a href="amitpandya.html"> Amit Pandya, DDS </a></li>
            <li> <a href="posterillos.html"> Posters & Illustrations </a></li>
            <li> <a href="banners.html"> Banners </a></li>
            <li> <a href="movieposters.html"> Movie Posters </a></li>
            <li> <a href="greetingcards.html"> Greeting Cards </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="images/portfolio/tmad1.jpg" width="420px" height="308" alt="
                           Trivedi Museum of Art and Design" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/tmad2.jpg" width="420px" height="315" alt="
                           Trivedi Museum of Art and Design" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/tmad3.jpg" width="420px" height="315" alt="
                           Trivedi Museum of Art and Design" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/tmad4.jpg" width="420px" height="315" alt="
                          Trivedi Museum of Art and Design" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/tmad5.jpg" width="420px" height="315" alt="
                          Trivedi Museum of Art and Design" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS  <sup>(I know I probably misused some of the elements so bear with me)</sup>

```
#about {
    float: left;
    width: 960px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border: 1px solid;

}

#print_list {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

#print_list li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
    text-align: right;
}

#print_list a, #print_list a:link, #print_list a:visited, #print_list a:active {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#print_list a:hover {
    color: #b13c19;
}

.images {
    float: right;
    right: 20px;
    width: 420px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: You mention that you are trying to replicate the "image below", but I don't see an image.

Comment: Actually, it appears that you may have posted only half a question. The html appears truncated, and there is no accompanying css.

Comment: ok the image didn't show up but thats ok.

Comment: sorry about that. forgot the css. the only html i forgot is the closing div tags for the "about" and "container"

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table with two columns and make the div (one on the right) scrollable.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <!-- First column -->  
    <td>
        <ul id="print_list">
            <li> <a href="eff.html"> <span style="color: #b13c19"> Earth Friendly
                  Foods </span> </a></li>
            <li> <a href="tmad.html"> Trivedi Museum of Art and Design </a></li>
            <li> <a href="amitpandya.html"> Amit Pandya, DDS </a></li>
            <li> <a href="posterillos.html"> Posters & Illustrations </a></li>
            <li> <a href="banners.html"> Banners </a></li>
            <li> <a href="movieposters.html"> Movie Posters </a></li>
            <li> <a href="greetingcards.html"> Greeting Cards </a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>

    <!-- Second column -->
    <td>
        <div class="images" style="overflow: scroll;">

            <img src="images/portfolio/tmad1.jpg" width="420px" height="308" alt="
                       Trivedi Museum of Art and Design" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/tmad2.jpg" width="420px" height="315" alt="
                       Trivedi Museum of Art and Design" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/tmad3.jpg" width="420px" height="315" alt="
                       Trivedi Museum of Art and Design" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/tmad4.jpg" width="420px" height="315" alt="
                      Trivedi Museum of Art and Design" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/tmad5.jpg" width="420px" height="315" alt=" 
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've thought about that, but I really dont want to use tables. I'm building this site to practice my html and css. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

[`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position) removes the element to which it is applied from the DOM flow.  If you know that there will always be a gutter of 220px on the left of the page then you can simply add 220px of margin to the `images` div:

```
.images {
    /* Your declarations go here */
    margin-left: 220px;
}
```

See also:

- [The quirks mode page on position](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html)
- [The full browser compatibility mode chart on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/css-fixed)